# How to measure Cycles per Byte of an Algorithm?

Tags: performance

I am trying to measure the cycles per byte for $\mathop{SHA-3}$ reference implementation. I am using [recommendations from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx) querying the performance counter. As you can see in the first snippet, cycles are measured before converting into microseconds. My code looks like the following:

```
QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);
SHA3_256(K_OUT, K_IN, length);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);

ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;
printf("Elapsed ticks: %.20f \n", ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart / (float)(length));
```

But the results are definitively wrong. It is mostly something smaller than $0.9$. I would guess a value around $30$ Cycles per Byte. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is borderline Off Topic (implementations details). I tried to edit it to make it inside the crypto.se scope. If you feel like it doesn't reflect what you want to ask, feel free to revert.

Comment: Also note that `QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency);` is useless in your case.

Answer (score 10):

To perform a good check, please use a large number of iterations (i.e. a `for` loop) of calls to the cryptographic primitive with your specific data size. Then average these out.

To avoid compiler optimizations, be sure to print out the result after the clock has been stopped. For instance, you could XOR all the outputs together and print that out. Otherwise the compiler may determine that your call has no side effects and simply remove the entire call to SHA-3.

Note that internal operations are usually performed on 64-bit or larger registers, i.e. 8 bytes at a time. It is perfectly possible to have sub-one scores - although I admit that for SHA-3 the value of 0.9 cycle/byte does not seem likely.

Comment: Don't just dodge the compiler optimizer. It's telling you something important- your test case is too trivial and doesn't reflect real-world usage. You may get a number this way, but it's not going to be useful.

Comment: @Puppy Too trivial or useful for *who*? Why is this comment below the answer instead of the question? Are you saying that it isn't useful to test cryptographic primitives, ever?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I think he is referring to how you mention that if you do not use the output of the function you are testing, that the compiler will optimize it out.  I think he was suggesting that the test should be more similar to real world usage.

Comment: I guess that testing the primitive in a cryptosystem of some kind is indeed more useful, if that's the goal. I guess above is useful when comparing different implementations of SHA-3 (or indeed other hash algorithms). In that case I don't see too much wrong with it, even with the trick of avoiding the compiler issue. Unfortunately I can only work with what was in the question and I think it's a bridge too far to call testing just the primitive "too trivial".

Comment: @Puppy If you bench marked in the way you advocate, that would also more or less make the results invalid as they can't be used as a relative gauge to other bench marked algorithms. Everyone else is using a synthetic benchmark (most other programs closed, hyper threading off, etc), so if your test deviates from the way everyone else tests, the results of your test would not necessarily align with other benchmark information. The testing only provides a relative performance metric anyways, the absolute value of cycles per byte will vary depending on platform and code and CPU usage.

Comment: @EllaRose: I also would like a good answer to the original question "How to measure Cycles per Byte of an Algorithm?". For my own benefit (and the benefit of others who obviously don't know the valid way of doing it), please post an answer briefly describing a valid test and perhaps linking to an example of how "everyone else tests".

Comment: @DavidCary There are actually a few answers related to the subject here on crypto.se already. Here's a few of them: [Calculating cycles per byte](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3945/29554), [What does a cycle mean in cryptography benchmarks](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5995/29554), [How to calculate cycles per byte](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8406/29554), [Ideal way to profile/performance-measure cipher implementations](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/37276/29554). Theres also [eBACS](http://bench.cr.yp.to/) and [Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html) benchmarks